# Unable to see DVD drive on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: dvd

I know that the drive is connected properly since I have Ubuntu installed along side Windows 7 and the drive works within Windows. I do not see it in the media folder as specified in other answers. When executing the following script within the terminal here are my finds. Please advise.

```
jamie@OptiPlex-790:~$ sudo lshw -C disk
[sudo] password for jamie: 
  *-disk                  
       description: ATA Disk
       product: SAMSUNG SSD PM83
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/sda
       version: CXM0
       serial: S0TYNZABC63105
       size: 119GiB (128GB)
       capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
       configuration: ansiversion=5 sectorsize=512 signature=b2e138ff
  *-cdrom
       description: DVD-RAM writer
       product: DVD+-RW GH70N
       vendor: HL-DT-ST
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/cdrom
       logical name: /dev/cdrw
       logical name: /dev/dvd
       logical name: /dev/dvdrw
       logical name: /dev/sr0
       version: A101
       capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
       configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
jamie@OptiPlex-790:~$
```

Comment: Can you see the drive in the left-hand column of your file manager? Clicking on it there will *mount* the drive and it will appear as a sub-directory of `/media` directory

Answer (score 1):

The output provided by you shows that the drivers of the dvd writer are installed and kernel is recognizing the hardware. In ubuntu 12.10, it won't show you the drive if there is no media in it. When you insert any dvd or cd in it, it will automatically mount it in the /media and show you the content. You can check also check where it is mounted by following command:

```
mount
```

Comment: Yes, my apologies as the last time I tried putting a DVD in to see if it would pop up it wouldn't, but after trying again it did. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

**1). This Covers the Unmounting and Mounting of the disk automatically.**

A lot of people have had this problem, as I first did with the dvd and cd mounting. You have to make a directory for the folder within media. Be sure to run as root.

> sudo -s
>
> cd mkdir /media/[folder_name]

If you have any error regarding read/write issues you will have to chmod

*Warning, If You do not know what you are doing I would suggest NOT doing this!*

> sudo -s
>
> cd /media
>
> chmod ugo+rwx

I hope this helped! The main problem is that the drive will not unmount itself after inserting a disk. Creating a directory solves this problem.

---

**2). As for seeing the driver I would suggest installing the drivers by first discovering the exact brand/model your cd drive is. Then try using synaptic to find the driver.**

> sudo -s
>
> apt-get install synaptic
>
> apt-get update

After the installation open a terminal or search the dash for synaptic.

> sudo -s
>
> synaptic

If it does not show you would then have to look for a source for the driver, which I would recommend using a search engine to find the source.